# Join two csv files

Tags: linux, csv, unix, join

I need to merge these two sorted csv files on 'contract' column (which is common for both files):

file1.csv

> data;client;contract
>
> Mar 04 2017;LA00024;1-456
>
> Mar 04 2017;LA00025;1-789

file2.csv

> contract;PdA
>
> 1-456;00024
>
> 1-789;00025

The output I'd like to get it is a unique table:

> data;client;contract;PdA
>
> Mar 04 2017;LA00024;1-456;00024
>
> Mar 04 2017;LA00025;1-789;00025

However using command

> $ join -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.2 -t";" -1 3 -2 1 file1.csv file2.csv

The result I get is just a line

> $ data;client;contract;PdA

The join doesn't return anything but the merge of the titles from input files?
Why does it act like this?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the files before `join`.

```
join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2 -t ';' -1 3 -2 1 <(sort -n -t";" -k3 file1.csv) <(sort -n -t";" -k1 file2.csv)
```

**PS:** For the sample data, the command in question worked for me. Required `,` in `-o FORMAT`.